# Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured

Tags: angular, typescript

**Angular version**:
**14.2.7**

I have installed a CSS library to my angular project (it is not publically available). Then, I've added it to `app.module.ts`:

```
 import { SapphireButtonModule } from '@sapphire-angular/core';

 imports: [
    SapphireButtonModule,
 ],
```

Having saved the file I get this:

[image]

I know there are many similiar questions but they were not answered clearly enough in my opinion and did not help. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know my answer will help you or not but I'm sure some of concepts related to build system you will know.

Any frontend library/framework uses build system to build project. Angular uses webpack for it. In my all project, whether it's Angular or React I always create a custom webpack config. Why becuase out of box they provide just a basic inbuilt webpack configuration.
In your case whatever Angular using is not supporting @ symbol in css. I personally prefer to use css-loader with MiniCssExtract and in case of scss a layer scss-loader also comes. Here is piece of code:

```
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
                // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                "css-loader",
                // Compiles Sass to CSS
                "sass-loader",
              ],
        }
```

I will advise you to look for How you can create a custom webpack config. Believe me you will know lots of new things.
For example, Out of box Angular don't compress your output file. But with custom webpack you can compress your output files to boost performance by reducing the size of output